# PostgreSQL: Paginate JSONB data

Tags: postgresql

This may be long shot but is there any way to limit JSONB data with query?

We are investigating the differences between MongoDB and PostgreSQL JSONB and this may be a critical factor.

Comment: Please be a little bit more precise. What exactly do you mean by "limit"?

Comment: You can use the JSON functions to convert the data to a set of rows on which you can use `LIMIT`. But I don't think that that is a design that will make you happy in the long run. I would look into normalizing the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used both MongoDB and PostgreSQL (using JSONB) and IMO, PostgreSQL wins 90% of the time.

This is because most data in real-life is inherently relational and PostgreSQL gives you the best of both worlds. It's a powerful relational database but also has the flexibility of JSONB when required (e.g. JSON can be perfect for unstructured data).

It's disadvantages are at humongous (*cough*) scale - MongoDB can win then e.g. when there are huge amounts of raw JSON data (or data which can be easily converted to JSON) with no/limited relations.

The power of PostgreSQL JSONB is best illustrated with an example: -

Lets create a table (`t`) as follows: -

```sql
create table t (
    id serial primary key, 
    data jsonb);
```

... with some demo data ...

```sql
insert into t (id, data) 
       values (1, '[{"name": "A", "age": 20},
                    {"name": "B", "age": 21},
                    {"name": "C", "age": 22},
                    {"name": "D", "age": 23},
                    {"name": "E", "age": 24},
                    {"name": "F", "age": 25},
                    {"name": "G", "age": 26}]'),
              (2, '[{"name": "H", "age": 27},
                    {"name": "I", "age": 28},
                    {"name": "J", "age": 29},
                    {"name": "K", "age": 30},
                    {"name": "L", "age": 31}]'),
              (3, '[{"name": "M", "age": 32},
                    {"name": "N", "age": 33},
                    {"name": "O", "age": 34},
                    {"name": "P", "age": 35},
                    {"name": "Q", "age": 36}]');
```

### 1. Simple select

If we simply select all from `t` we get 3 rows with a JSONB array in the `data` column.

```sql
select * 
  from t;  

----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id | data
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"age": 20, "name": "A"}, {"age": 21, "name": "B"}, {"age": 22, "name": "C"}, {"age": 23, "name": "D"}, {"age": 24, "name": "E"}, {"age": 25, "name": "F"}, {"age": 26, "name": "G"}]
  2 | [{"age": 27, "name": "H"}, {"age": 28, "name": "I"}, {"age": 29, "name": "J"}, {"age": 30, "name": "K"}, {"age": 31, "name": "L"}]
  3 | [{"age": 32, "name": "M"}, {"age": 33, "name": "N"}, {"age": 34, "name": "O"}, {"age": 35, "name": "P"}, {"age": 36, "name": "Q"}]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### 2. Select + Unnest

We can then "un-nest" the JSONB array in the `data` column by using the `jsonb_array_elements` function - this will return 17 rows of `id` and `data` JSONB objects.

```sql
select id, 
       jsonb_array_elements(data) 
  from t;

----+--------------------------
 id | data
----+--------------------------
  1 | {"age": 20, "name": "A"}
  1 | {"age": 21, "name": "B"}
  1 | {"age": 22, "name": "C"}
  1 | {"age": 23, "name": "D"}
  1 | {"age": 24, "name": "E"}
  1 | {"age": 25, "name": "F"}
  1 | {"age": 26, "name": "G"}
  2 | {"age": 27, "name": "H"}
  2 | {"age": 28, "name": "I"}
  2 | {"age": 29, "name": "J"}
  2 | {"age": 30, "name": "K"}
  2 | {"age": 31, "name": "L"}
  3 | {"age": 32, "name": "M"}
  3 | {"age": 33, "name": "N"}
  3 | {"age": 34, "name": "O"}
  3 | {"age": 35, "name": "P"}
  3 | {"age": 36, "name": "Q"}
-------------------------------
```

### 3. Select + Unnest + Pagination

We can then paginate the previous "un-nested" query above: -

```sql
select id, 
       jsonb_array_elements(data) 
  from t 
 limit 5; -- return 1st 5 

----+---------------------------
 id | data
----+---------------------------
  1 | {"age": 20, "name": "A"}
  1 | {"age": 21, "name": "B"}
  1 | {"age": 22, "name": "C"}
  1 | {"age": 23, "name": "D"}
  1 | {"age": 24, "name": "E"}
--------------------------------

select id, 
       jsonb_array_elements(data) 
  from t 
 limit 5 offset 5; -- return next 5

----+---------------------------
 id | data
----+---------------------------
  1 | {"age": 25, "name": "F"}
  1 | {"age": 26, "name": "G"}
  2 | {"age": 27, "name": "H"}
  2 | {"age": 28, "name": "I"}
  2 | {"age": 29, "name": "J"}
--------------------------------
```

### 4. Select + Un-nest + Pagination + Re-nest

We can take this 1 step further and can group by `id` again and put the JSON back into an array using the `jsonb_agg` function: -

```sql
with t_unnested as (
    select id, 
           jsonb_array_elements(data) as data
      from t 
     limit 5 offset 5
)
select id, jsonb_agg (data) 
  from t_unnested
 group by id;

----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id | data
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"age": 25, "name": "F"}, {"age": 26, "name": "G"}]
  2 | [{"age": 27, "name": "H"}, {"age": 28, "name": "I"}, {"age": 29, "name": "J"}]
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### 5. Select + Un-nest + Pagination + Re-nest + Custom Object

We can take the previous query and re-construct a new object with new fields e.g. `person_id` and `person_info`.  This
will return a single column with a new custom JSONB object (again a row per `id`).

```sql
with t_unnested as (
    select id, 
           jsonb_array_elements(data) as data
      from t 
     limit 5 offset 5
),
t_person as (
    select jsonb_build_object (
               'person_id', id,
               'person_info', jsonb_agg (data)
           ) as person
      from t_unnested
     group by id
)
select person from t_person;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 person
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"person_id": 1, "person_info": [{"age": 25, "name": "F"}, {"age": 26, "name": "G"}]}
 {"person_id": 2, "person_info": [{"age": 27, "name": "H"}, {"age": 28, "name": "I"}, {"age": 29, "name": "J"}]}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### 6. Select + Un-nest + Pagination + Re-nest + Custom Object + Further Re-Nest

The previous query returned 2 rows, we can create a single row by once again using the `jsonb_agg` function i.e.

```sql
with t_unnested as (
    select id, 
           jsonb_array_elements(data) as data
      from t 
     limit 5 offset 5
),
t_person as (
    select jsonb_build_object (
               'person_id', id,
               'person_info', jsonb_agg (data)
           ) as person
      from t_unnested
     group by id
)
select jsonb_agg(person) from t_person;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 person
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"person_id": 1, "person_info": [{"age": 25, "name": "F"}, {"age": 26, "name": "G"}]}, {"person_id": 2, "person_info": [{"age": 27, "name": "H"}, {"age": 28, "name": "I"}, {"age": 29, "name": "J"}]}]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hopefully this shows the power of JSONB / PostgreSQL in both storing JSONB, un-nesting (and re-nesting) JSON arrays with pagination.

Comment: Thanks man. Ended up going with MongoDB. Just needed a way to query anonymous previous user defined types. Postgres queries/tables became complicated. Hope your solution helps someone else.

Comment: If there are no relationships MongoDB can be a solid choice, it's quick to get going as well and the documentation is good. Best of luck.